# Meteor: Session problems

Tags: session, meteor

Im getting this error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'set' of undefined
```

Code is:

```
    Router.map(function() {
        this.route('/payment_return/:invoice_no/:amount/', {
            where: 'server',
            onBeforeAction: function() {
                console.log("result");
                result = paypal_return(this.params.invoice_no,this.params.amount,this.params.query.token,this.params.query.PayerID);
                console.log(result);
                if (result)
                {
                    var tokens = this.params.amount*10;
                    console.log(tokens);
                var playerId = this._id;
                Session.set('selectedUser', playerId);
                    var selectedUser = Session.get('selectedUser');
                    Meteor.call('updateTokens', selectedUser, tokens);
                    this.response.end("Payment captured successfully");
                }
                else
                {
                    this.response.end("Error in processing payment");
                }


            }
        });
    });
```

In, methods.js

```
Meteor.methods({
    'updateTokens': function(selectedUser, tokens){
        check(selectedUser, String);
        check(tokens, Number);
        var currentUserId = Meteor.userId();
        if(currentUserId){
            Meteor.users.update(selectedUser,
                { $inc: { 'profile.tokens': tokens}});
        }
    }
})
```

Basically, trying to update user's token amount after successful payment, but unfortunately it's returning just that error.

Answer (score 1):

Sessions are only available in client side... Not sure where you are trying to call Session, but if Session package is included and you are calling Sessions.set/get on client it should work.

Comment: theyre stored in my routes.js under lib. im not entirely sure if those sre client or server side tbh... if theyre server,  how do make it work?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like API call to me, so I will suggest you to use meteorhacks:picker

Then you can add on your server side:

```
    var paymentRoutes= Picker.filter(function(req, res) {
  return req.method == "POST"; //OR GET WHATEVER YOU NEED
});

    paymentRoutes.route('/payment_return/:invoice_no/:amount/', 
    function(params, req, res, next) {
      //UPDATE TOKEN
    });
```

Comment: can i use this eith the outher route code thst i have or only one or the other?

Comment: you can use them bolt just don't use same route. I mean u can route your blaze templates etc. with Router and use picker for REST API calls like this one

Comment: forgive me if I'm wrong but what info  the fromREST API that im calling? will this solve the issue of returning the userid?  thats the only info needed..  sorry im new and just confused

Answer (score 1):

```
var paymentRoutes= Picker.filter(function(req, res) {
  return req.method == "GET" || "POST";
});

paymentRoutes.route('/payment_return/:invoice_no/:amount/', function(params, req, res, next) {
      result = paypal_return(params.invoice_no,params.amount,params.query.token, this.userId);
      if (result){
          var tokens = this.params.amount*10;
          var playerId = this.userId;
          Meteor.users.update({_id:playerId},{ $inc: { 'profile.tokens': tokens}});
          res.end("Payment captured successfully");
      }else{
          res.end("Error in processing payment");
      }
});
```

I hope this will be helpful, Cheers

Comment: This route actually relies on another route called "payment", which code is, Router.map(function() {
 this.route('/payment/:invoice_no/:amount/', {
  where: 'server',
  action: function() {
   var amount = parseInt(this.params.amount);
   var url = generate_URL_for_payment_authorization(this.params.invoice_no,this.params.amount);

   if (url == null)
   {
    this.response.end("error");
   }
   this.response.writeHead(301, { 'Location': url});
   this.response.end();
  }
 });
});... do i replicate the same? also, instead of this.response.writeHead, isi t res.writeHead?

Comment: im assuming it relies on that route because I am returned with TypeError: Cannot read property 'invoice_no' of undefined, so it wasn't passed maybe im not sure

Comment: or isit template based? coz theres an events code for it where the user puts in invoice_no and amount.. could it be that?